# AutoLayout labels getting cut off on right side of screen

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard, xcode6

I'm trying to use Auto Layout for a custom Table View Cell in my app.

I can't seem to get the constraints quite right.

I layed the labels out in the custom Table View Cell, but the labels are still getting cut off. Any ideas?

Thanks! Will post anything else needed. Tried to show needed info in picture below:

Debugging in Xcode.  Somehow what shows in Simulator looks different than in Xcode debug.

Here's the width of my TableView shown:
[image]

**UPDATE:**
The problem here was related to what user matt said in the accepted answer, but I wanted to make the Q&A a bit clearer now that I have it figured out for anyone else that comes across this.

In his initial comment, he mentioned the Xcode View debugging, which was great and I was able to dig into a little bit more.  Its called the Assistant Editor: Device Preview, where you are able to see the layout and layers of what is onscreen to see if maybe you have labels overlapping or going offscreen based on the device it is running on. If you want to check multiple device sized, just hit the plus icon in the lower left hand corner of this picture.
[image]

This helped me find overlapping layers and sizing issues with the TableView.  I was able to see how it looked on each device size.

What also helps here sometimes to use the Pin menu. Sometimes the labels can run off screen because it doesn't know where the constraints of the cell are based on the device size. So your label can run offscreen if the label is based off of a landscape layout but the device is an iPhone 5 and is in Portrait for example. This is the Pin menu:

[image]

Hope that makes sense and gives some more color to the problem.  Let me know if you have any questions at all, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Hi again. You know about Xcode 6 view debugging, right? (It's like Reveal.) So use Xcode 6 view debugging to see what's really happening here.

Comment: @matt yeah I've been trying to figure it out because its showing me something different than what I run in the Simulator, so I'm not sure what's happening?  I updated my question to show 2 extra pictures of what the simulator vs view debugging shows.  If you have any idea why thats happening do tell.

Comment: Well, that looks like exactly what I suggested over on the other question you asked - it is not the labels that are the problem, it's the table view itself that is too wide.

Comment: My table view isn't stretched out on the storyboard past where the View Controller is so I'm not sure how to change that.  Obviously what you're saying must be right, but I'm not sure how to change it since it's fitting the bounds of the View Controller in the Storyboard ya know?

Comment: @matt I added a picture to show exactly what that View/TableView looks like.  The table view isn't stretching outside of the View, which is the only thing I would be able to think of why it is doing what its doing.  And its not showing the TableView being an obvious bad size when I looked at the View in the View Debugging.  So I'm confused

Comment: You've got a table view inside a view. That's already pretty unusual; usually, a table view _is_ the view controller's view (and you use a table view controller to manage it). So it looks like something pretty strange is going on with your configuration of this table view. My guess is that you're doing something wrong with how you get the table view (and its superview?) into the interface to start with. You may be mismanaging something at the view controller level.

Comment: In terms of doing something wrong with how I get the tableview/superview into the interface, I just dragged the TableView into the View Controller, so I'm not sure how I would have gotten something wrong there.  I'm sure once again you're on to something, I just am still not sure how I would even figure out what the answer here is ya know

Comment: "I just dragged the TableView into the View Controller" - No, you dragged it into the view controller's _view_. Now you have to worry about its size. The view controller's view is automatically resized, but the table view is not. So... what constraints do you have _on the table view?_ Doing something about its size is completely up to you.

Comment: Ah I see the distinction your making.  I didn't put any constraints on the table view, so I'm guessing I should put a 0 constraint on each side?  Thanks matt!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you are using auto layout but you have not done anything about *sizing the table view*. The table view here is not your view controller's view; it is a subview. Your view controller's view is automatically sized to the size of the device / window, but its subviews are not automatically resized. So you are ending up with the table view much too wide for the device; the whole table is sticking off into space on the right side.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for spelling it out a little more here too, so at a minimum, I'm going to need some sort of constraint on the right size it sounds like

Comment: No, not "at a minimum". Constraints _must_ determine everything's size and position _completely_.

Comment: K guess I should have been clearer when I wrote that, not at a minimum but as "one of the minimums", you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use a trailing space from the right side of your labels to the edge of their superview, and set it to `greater than` instead of `equals` with a value of ~ 5

Comment: Added another screenshot to my original question showing what I tried per your suggestion, and for some reason its still cutting off, does anything stick out to you that I'm missing?  Thanks Levi!

Comment: It looks fine, but maybe it's superview is off then. You should place a breakpoint in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `willDisplayCellForRowAtIndexPath` (maybe better here) method and see which of the cell's subviews has a greater width than it should.

Answer (score 2):

Review the constraints of your tableview with the View. Draw cell border, label border and tableview border with different colors to know which elements do not display correctly.

Ex:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

...
cell.layer.border.width = 1;
cell.layer.border.color = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Hi @tyt_g207, thanks for the response, I updated my original question with two screenshots from the Xcode 6 view debugging that sort of show the same thing.  The problem as you'll see is that the Simulator is running something that looks slightly different than View Debugging and I'm not sure why?

Comment: It depends on the target that you run. I suppose that you have fixed the size (in Simulated Metrics) so that the content is not stretched automatically. Add some NSLog() in your programme to show the frame of your View, TableView, Cells. There is an API NSStringFromCGRect() to view each frame size.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that worked for me to solve views being clipped was to uncheck "Constrain to margins" in Auto Layout.

[image]