# Detail Text and Accessory Don't show

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

When I add data to my tableViews data source (an array of custom objects), the only thing that shows up is the textLabel, not the detailTextLabel or the accessory. Do I have something misconfigured? Am I doing something wrong in my code? Do I need to add more into my code?

Here is the code for the entire ViewController (excluding the alert to add new items):

```
class ObjectiveViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var objectiveArray = [Objective]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objectiveArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ObjectivePrototypeCell") as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text = objectiveArray[indexPath.row].name
    if objectiveArray[indexPath.row].hours == 0 {
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(objectiveArray[indexPath.row].minutes) + ":" + String(objectiveArray[indexPath.row].seconds)
    } else {
        cell.detailTextLabel!.text = String(objectiveArray[indexPath.row].hours) + ":" + String(objectiveArray[indexPath.row].minutes) + ":" + String(objectiveArray[indexPath.row].seconds)
    }
    return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

This is how the prototype cell is configured:

[image: Prototype cell configuration.]

This is how the prototype looks in my storyboard:

[image: Prototype cell in my storyboard]

This is the outcome when I add a new cell to the table:

[image: The outcome after adding a new objective to my table]

Comment: Weird. Does it *look* correct in your storyboard? You can see the light grey "Detail" placeholder label on the right-hand side there?

Comment: Are you registering the cell with the table view? If so, delete the line where you do that.

Comment: Please show more details about uitableviewcontroller,I think the code about cellForRowAtIndexPath is right

Comment: @matt I already was not registering the cell with the table view.

Comment: @WenchenHuang I added all the code for the ViewController excluding the import statement (UIKit) and the code for the alert to add new items.

Comment: Did you add constraints to your table view? Are you using size classes? I'm wondering if the right side of the cell is off the screen.

Comment: @rdelmar You're exactly right. Constraints are the issue. How would I fix that? The size class I'm in is w: Any h: Any.

Comment: @rdelmar Ooooh, I like that theory. We just had one like that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26642997/341994

Comment: Add constraints to the left and right edges of the table view to the left and right edges of the main view (as well as any you want vertically to define its position).

Comment: @rdelmar Would you be offended if I closed this as a duplicate of the other one?

Comment: @matt, nope, that's fine. It does look like a dup.