# Swift 4/Xcode 9 - UITableView custom cell getting cut off on the right

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, autolayout, cells

I'm having trouble setting constraints on a tableView that I've inserted into my View Controller. It's occupying around half of the view and despite pinning it to the sides of the view, it seems to maintain the same size dimensions when I switch to a smaller iPhone causing it to overlap on the right side. I'm using a custom cell with 2 labels. I've tried the suggestions in this thread with a similar question: [AutoLayout labels getting cut off on right side of screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26641164/autolayout-labels-getting-cut-off-on-right-side-of-screen) but haven't had any success.

[Here is how it looks when being viewed on the iPhone 8 plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCTS7.png)

[and here's how it looks on the iPhone SE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5Be.png)

[Here are the constraints that I set for the tableview.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MUCD.png)

Comment: From your picture, it appears that the cell's are correctly constrained to the table view, but the table view is not constrained to the view controller.

Comment: I added a photo to show the constraints that I set for the table view. Any idea what I might be missing of what I did wrong?